# TextJoin two columns and paste it on new worksheet using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Excel Cells]

From the table above, I would like to use Excel VBA with a for loop and `TEXTJOIN` to combine the cells so that it looks like A1, B2, C3 and paste it to a new worksheet.

Results
[image]

Comment: Why not use a worksheet formula?

Comment: Because the length of both columns are not constant. And there is also other functions except this. So I would be very grateful if I can use macro to perform this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the last row of both columns then extend the formula of textjoin till max of both... Something like this below... No need of for loop though...

```
' Input is in "Sheet1" & Output in "Sheet2"

Sub join()

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
lRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(lRow1, lRow2)

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Range("A1").Formula = "=TEXTJOIN(,0,Sheet1!A1:B1)"
Selection.Copy
Range("A1:A" & lRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: I get it know thank you very much!